# JPanels, Listeners and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, jframe, jpanel

For a school project I'm writing a BlackJack card game in JAVA.

After a few steps within the program, my whole computer system slows down/stutters and some areas within the JFrame turn black. No repainting seems te be happening.

I will give you some program details in words rather then submitting the code.

I have done some extensive extending of almost every GUI component to give it the look and feel that I want. Almost every child of JComponent that I use has got its paintComponent rewriten with custom image backgrounds and anti-aliasing where applicable.

In my (custom) JFrame I load an extended version of JPanel. This panel holds all the GUI components for that screen. When I want to switch screen (go to a different part of the program), I switch to another extended version of JPanel. I do this by removing all elements from the JFrame and add the new panel. These different panels implements ActionListeners and FocusListeners.

At this point my thoughts are leaning towards a thread handling issue. My theory for the moment is this: When a panel is constructed for display in the JFrame (each on different stages within te program), the previous constructed panels aren't realy 'destroyed', and the Listeners of those panels remain active.

My question for you people is, wether this theory holds ground... And in that case, is there a way to 'kill' these panels or at least stop the listening?

If my theory doesn't make sense, what else could be causing these symptoms? Could it be the extensive overwriting of the paintComponent methods?

Any ideas would be highly appriciated!

Regards Wilco

Comment: Without seeing code, I really doubt that anyone will be able to help you.  One thing - I don't see why you're removing all the components from the old JPanel - that's not necessary.  Are you running out of memory?  The behaviour you describe sounds like you might be.

Answer (score 0):

> When a panel is constructed for display in the JFrame (each on different stages within te program), the previous constructed panels aren't realy 'destroyed', and the Listeners of those panels remain active.

No. Events are only dispatched to the component that has focus. It a comonents doesn't have focus then it won't received system generated events like KeyEvents and MouseEvents. So if a panel isn't visible then it won't receive events.

> I switch to another extended version of JPanel. I do this by removing all elements from the JFrame and add the new panel.

This is not the best design. It is better to use a [Card Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which was designed for this purpose.

> Almost every child of JComponent that I use has got its paintComponent rewriten with custom image backgrounds and anti-aliasing where applicable

Then you probably have problems with your custom painting. What happens when you just use the standard components without custom painting?